# How to preview external files ( pdf, word, ppt etc ) which stored in my firebase storage without downloading it?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

me and my team making an social media application for office using react native and expo managed work flow , in which we decided to allow employee of office to upload their files (pdf , doc , ppt etc ) and **view the content of the file without downloading it**.

I used third party libraries like react-native-doc-viewer , react-native-file-viewer for that but those library cant be used in my app because those libraries are not maintained well.

i tried webview for previewing documents but in my mobile when i tried this **file gets download instead of previewing it**.

can you help me to solve that problem . Suggest the way to preview files stored in my firebase storage without downloading it.

sorry for my English, i am not good in english .

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the file URL from your firebase storage and append it to the google document viewer to be viewed in a regular WebView, I think this might work:

```
  const googleURL= `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${fileUrl}`;

  return <WebView source={{ uri: googleURL}} />;
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working in mobile , while i open link in my laptop it works